# Discord.js - module export doesnt work anymore

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I used the module export for my TOKEN to make index.js look cleaner, so my index.js looked like that:

```
const TOKEN = m.TOKEN;
```

and my config.js (where my TOKEN was stored) looked like that:

```
const TOKEN = '<token>';
exports.TOKEN = TOKEN;
```

I accidentally deleted my index.js and re-did it, but now it doesnt work anymore. I always get the error "An invalid token was provided.". What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's much more common to use a JSON file to hold plain values, you can work with [module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)s as shown in the setup below.

---

`config.js`:

```js
exports.TOKEN = 'abcd1234';
```

`index.js`:

```js
const { TOKEN } = require('./config.js'); // path may vary
```

---

`{ TOKEN }` is part of the [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax. [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) returns the target module's [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) property, which in this case, is an object; you can extract the property you need and use it later.

Comment: Oh and btw is there a way to use the module export on commands? like switch functions and if statements?